# Quick question on Bitwise operations

Tags: boolean-algebra

I have some questions for homework to do with Bitwise operations, now it's a simple task but it doesn't actually explain how to handle the questions which is why I'm asking here before I begin attempting the lot of them (10 similar questions)

First one:

```
 0010-1110-0010-1100 or 1110-0000-1110-0001
```

Do I have to compare the first set of 4 values on the first one with the second?
So would it be 0010 OR 1110? Which would equal to 1110 for the first set? Or is it done differently? Thanks for replies

Comment: It should be stated in the homework, but intuitively (and suggested by the term *bitwise*) I would **or** the single 
$0/1,\;$ i.e.
$$0010-1110-0010-1100$$ or
$$1110-0000-1110-0001$$
gives
$$1110-1110-1110-1101$$

Comment: Thanks for the input, it states how to do another one which is just "not 1110-0000-1110-0001" but it doesn't state how to do the one I had asked above at all. I'm going to do the rest as you said and hope they're correct lol